# PHP側でFORM上のラベルの内容を取得したい

Tags: php, html5

皆様いつもお世話になっております。
インターネットでの検索方法が悪いのか、標題の達成方法が分からず頭を悩ましています。
PHP内で、INPUT要素やリストボックス=SELECT要素の内容の取得方法だと、よく取り上げている記事があるのですが、label要素の内容取得方法を取り上げているのが　見当たらなく．．．
http://cly7796.net/wp/php/try-to-send-the-value-of-the-various-form/
でもやはりlabelに関しては取り上げられておりませんでした。

一先ずは同一name名が羅列するlabelでなく、ページ上単一のname属性のlabelでよいので、PHP内での内容把握方法（JQueryでいう.html）を教えてくださいませんか？

## ====質問====

以下HTML上のlabel（name=tname）の内容を、PHP内で把握する方法を教えてください。

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">受注先</td>
        <td class="extd"><button class="t9cdsrch" type="button"><img src="img/検索.png"></button>
            <input type="text" name="t9cd" id="tcd" style="width:45px;"><label name="t9name" id="t9name"></label>
            <label name="t9telno" id="t9telno"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="extd">〒<label name="t9postno" id="t9postno">　：</label><label name="t9address" id="t9address"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">出荷先</td>
        <td class="extd"><button class="s9cdsrch" type="button"><img src="img/検索.png"></button>
            <input type="text" name="s9cd"  id="scd" style="width:45px;"><label name="s9name" id="s9name"></label>
            <label name="s9telno" id="s9telno"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="extd">〒<label name="s9postno" id="s9postno">　：</label><label name="s9address" id="s9address"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: labelはformで送信されないものになります。それをPHP側でPOSTもしくはGETにより受信したいということですか？

Comment: keitaro_so様　ご支援をいつもありがとうございます。そのとおりです、恐れていたことが．．．POSTで取得できればと考えていましたが、PHP内で取得できれば手段に拘りはありません。

Comment: 「PHP内で取得できれば」という部分がよくわかりませんが、labelタグに記述する内容はPHP側から出力する内容になると思いますので、PHPにも同じ内容が記述できると思います。

Comment: もしかしてユーザが入力した内容をページ間で引き回したいということですか？であればformを利用するのであればinputのtype=hiddenを利用する方法がありますが、、、

Comment: JavaScriptのAjaxで、ラベルに内容を表示しています。
各INPUT要素のchange・blurイべントの発火から、DB参照で取得した各コードの名称などです。

SUBMITボタン押下のタイミングで、INPUT要素だけでなく画面上のほぼ全ての要素の内容を
PHP側で登録しようと考えていましたが．．．
頭が痛くなってきました。簡単に内容を認識できるものと思っていましたが、前回PHPから格納した内容を
確保しておくべき、ということですかね？

Comment: Ajaxを利用してDBから作成したラベルであれば、そのDBデータのプライマリIDをinputのhiddenに埋め込んで、そのIDを利用して再度PHP側でDBを参照して名称等は取得できると思います。

Comment: keitaro_so様、いつも大変御世話になっております。
ご見解の中でいわれているプライマリIDというのは一般的な表現であって、PHP上の何か私が知らない技術があるわけではないのですよね？？
単純に、PHP側でもう一度DBを参照することをご提案されているわけですよね？？
入力された内容を元にAjaxでDBから得てきた情報ですから、DB参照のためのネタ=INPUT要素はPOSTで渡ってきています。

当方が達成したいことの手段は2択あって
①Ajaxで得た各コードの名称を、ラベルではないINPUT項目（hidden）に格納してPHP側で利用する。
②PHP側に渡る全ての内容を信用すべきでなく、渡ってくる最低限のINPUT要素を精査の上で利用（DB参照しなおし）して
ラベル情報を再取得する

どちらか、ということでしょうか？認識に間違いがないかご見解を頂けましたら幸いです。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68859/discussion-between-keitaro-so-and-saya24)しましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formタグでPOSTやGETで値を渡せる部品タグは

- input
- textarea
- select
- bottun

です。

labelタグは値を渡すことはできません。

Comment: 常識かもしれませんが　私は知りませんでした。色々とありがとうございました。頭が上がりません